# Can someone recognize the font on this logo?

Tags: fonts

Can anybody recognize the 2 fonts on this logo?
http://www.networkdance.com/logo.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to search on this site : http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

You can upload an image and find the font on it. Very usefull !